# Let g : ℝ -> ℝ be a continuous function on ℝ such that g(2) + g(6) = g(3) + g(5) Is it true that c exists such that g(c) = 1/2 * (g(c+1) + g(c-1))

Tags: real-analysis

This question screams Intermediate Value Theorem. However, no bounds were specified for testing. I tried using the bounds [2, 6]

I have let f(x) = g(x) - 1/2*(g(x+1) + g(x-1)) 
A bit of manipulation yields
f(3) + f(4) + f(5) = 0

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Your "bit of manipulation" cannot be correct, as the left side, when expanded in terms of $g$, would depend on $g(1)$ which is neither constrained anywhere nor does it appear on the right side.  Instead, try finding an expression for $f(3)+f(4)+f(5)$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring That was helpful! Thanks!

Comment: @kmtllesur Do you see how to finish?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes =) We can split into cases in which the trivial case is that f(3) = f(4) = f(5) = 0, then we already have c. Otherwise, there would be at least 1 of 3, 4, 5 that yields a positive value and another value which yields a negative value. Since f is continuous, then we can use IVT to deduce such c exists within the range.

Comment: @kmtlesur Oh, you've got the very same idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g(2)+g(6) = g(3) + g(5)$

$\rightarrow g(6)-g(5) = g(3) - g(2)$

Let $f(x) = g(x+1) - g(x)$

$\rightarrow f(5)  = f(2) = k$

---

$\displaystyle g(c) = \frac{1}{2}(g(c+1)+g(c-1))$

$\rightarrow 2g(c) = g(c+1) + g(c-1)$

$\rightarrow g(c+1) - g(c) = g(c) -g(c-1)$

$\rightarrow f(c) = f(c-1)$

Let $h(x) = f(x) - f(x-1)$

Then, all we have to do is to check whether there's a $c$ satisfying $h(c) = 0$

$f(5)-f(2) = k-k = 0$

$f(5) - f(2) = (f(5) - f(4)) + (f(4)-f(3)) + (f(3) - f(2))$

$=h(4) + h(3) + h(2)$

$\rightarrow h(5) + h(4) + h(3) = 0$

As $g$ is continuous, $f$ and $h$ are also continuous.

If any of $h(3)$, $h(4)$, $h(5)$ is $0$, then the proof ends.

So, assume none of them are $0$.

If all of their signs are same, $h(5) + h(4) + h(3)$ can't be $0$

Thus, one of their sign must be different with others.

Suppose $h(a)$ and $h(b)$ have different signs.
($a,b \in \{3, 4, 5\}$ and $a\neq b$)

Then, with the IVT, there's a c s.t. $h(c) = 0$ where $c \in (min(a,b), max(a,b))$.

Thus, there exists such $c$ satisfying the condition.

Comment: +1. This reminds me of the Horizontal Chord Theorem:  If $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ is continuous with $f(0)=f(1)$ then for every $n\in\Bbb N$ there exists $x_n\in [0,1-1/n]$ such that $f(x_n)=f(x_n+1/n)$.

Comment: Oh, I thought it could be generalized, and there it is. Thanks!

Comment: If $r\in (0,1)$ and $r$ is not the reciprocal of an integer, the Horizontal Chord Theorem will not guarantee some $x$ such that $f(x)=f(x+r)$. E.g. with some trial & error you can get a continuous piece-wise linear $f$ with $f(0)=f(1)$ but $f(x)\ne f(x+2/3)$ for any $x\in [0,1/3].$

Comment: In my guess, such $x$ exists when there's a positive integer $s$ s.t. $rs = b-a$ where $f(a) = f(b)$ and $a<b$